# Vue.js instead mustache for generating e-mail body?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

We have hard email body with static header, hard dynamic middle part and dinamic bottom. This time I deside to use on server-side Vue.js as Mustache on steroids to generate this email bodies.

My first test was filed. can you help me what't wrong with it?

**template.html**

```html
<div>
    <h1>Hello world!!!</h1>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="eachData of data">
            {{eachData}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**email.test.js**

```js
    it('vue', async ()  => {
        const vue = new Vue({
            template: await fs.readFile('templates/main.html', {encoding:'UTF-8'}),
            data: {
                    data: [1, 2, 3, 4,]
            },
        }).$mount()
        console.log(vue.$el)
    })
```

**output**

> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>
> ```
> at Vue.$mount (C:\Users\BARANOV_ALY\WebstormProjects\sova-server\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.js:11885:16)
> ```

Comment: How is your app structured? Looks like you are mixing .vue files which require a bundler like webpack with .html files, which require vue-server-renderer see https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#installation

Comment: I haven't .vue files in project at all. This is regular express.js app. Some routers should generate e-mails like so:
1. Load template from .html file. 
2. Create vue instance with loaded template and data.
3. Render it to get e-mail body.
4. Send it.

Comment: @ellisdod Oh great! It works with vue-server-renderer great! Exactly what we need. Thank you very much!